# Add Values to Tuple

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I was originally using a IDictonary to store string values in my MVC model - as below:

```
public IDictionary<string, string> MyValues { get; set; }

MyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Name", "Joe Bloggs"}, 
    {"Address", "Main Street"}
};
```

The above is set in my model constructor and I also set other values when I get the model by doing:

```
var model = new MyModel();

model.MyValues .Add("foo", "bar");
```

In my view then I have the following:

```
@{
    var myValues = Model.MyValues.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < myValues .Count(); ++i)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Id", myValues[i].Key)
        @Html.Hidden("Value", myValues[i].Value)
    }
}
```

I need to now change this functionality and instead of an IDictoinary implement this with a Tuple

I have just changed the MyValues in my model so far to be:

```
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> MyValues { get; set; }
```

I am not sure how to implement the same functionality I had in my model constructor, setting other values in the model and then enumerating this in the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as:

```
MyValues = new List<Tuple<string,string>>
{
    Tuple.Create("Name", "Joe Bloggs"), 
    Tuple.Create("Address", "Main Street")
};
```

and:

```
model.MyValues.Add(Tuple.Create("foo", "bar"));
```

and:

```
@{
    var myValues = Model.MyValues;

    foreach (var tuple in myValues)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("Id", tuple.Item1);
        @Html.Hidden("Value", tuple.Item2);
    }
}
```

But you should change `MyValues` from being `IEnumerable` to `IList` or `ICollection` better, to say that adding is possible.

Comment: D'oh - and the logic in the view should remain the same

Comment: first approach is correct but second is not,you can't add to an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Selman22 - you mean unable to do this - public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> MyValues { get; set; } - what is the correct way to achieve that - just use a List?

Comment: @whiteknight if you want to be able to use MyValues.Add, at least you need to change property type to `IList<Tuple<string, string>> `

Comment: Can you explain as to why the IEnumerable would not work - for my own understanding - Thanks :)

Comment: because Add method is defined in IList<T> interface. and IENumerable doesn't inherit from IList. So, it's immutable unless you cast it to some type that has Add method.

Comment: @Selman22, to be strict, `Add` is defined in `ICollection<T>` interface. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Selman22, nope - `IList<T>` inherits `ICollection<T>`, not opposite way :)