# How to fill tuple in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have got the Tuple as:

```
 private Tuple<double, double, int>[] circle;
```

I trired to add and element using `add()` method. But there is not exist.

How to add element in Tuple array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Values to Tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381646/add-values-to-tuple)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget tuples for a second. How do you fill *any* arrays?

```
private int[] _numbers; // now what?
```

The answer is that arrays, in C#, have immutable size - they must be allocated during initialization, and that's the size they have. Once you've initialized them, you can assign values to the array members by index:

```
_numbers = new int[5];
_numbers[0] = 5;
circle = new Tuple<double,double,int>[5];
circle[0] = new Tuple<double,double,int>(1.0, 2.0, 3);
```

If you're coming in from a different language and expect a variable-length array that can be added to, what you're looking for is .NET's `List<T>` class, which can be initialized empty, and have members added and removed.

```
private List<Tuple<double,double,int>> circle;
circle = new List<Tuple<double,double,int>>();
circle.Add(new Tuple<double,double,int>(3.0, 2.0, 1));
```

Comment: So, do you recommend me to use list of tuples?

Comment: Since I have no idea what you're writing and what your needs are, no, I don't recommend anything.

Comment: Then how to update value in list by index? for example circle[index][,,3]? Only last value in tuple

Comment: Tuples in .NET are immutable. Once created, they cannot be updated. It seems that you don't really need a tuple here. Why not just create a class with three fields?

Comment: Maybe, but can I replace list element with tuple inside? I mean if exist list element with index 0, I add another element with index 0. Will it replace old value?

Comment: Please read up on arrays in C#. It's such a fundamental topic.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add elements to an array of tuples (or to array of anything else, for that matter), but you do have a number of options for creating an array of tuples:

- You can create a fixed-size array, and then populate it later, or
- You can create a fixed-size array, and populate it right away, or
- You can create a `List`, add items to it, and convert it to an array when you are done adding elements to it.

The third option is the most flexible. This is how it looks:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<double,double,int>>();
list.Add(Tuple.Create(1.5, 1.7, 9));
list.Add(Tuple.Create(2.6, 3.8, 11));
circle = list.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, so in third option is not necessary to define default size of list?

Comment: @OPV Correct, the third option lets you postpone specifying the size of the array until after all its elements are placed in the list.